# how do i make button works like pressing enter from keyboard in javascript?

Tags: javascript

HTML :

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){doSomething1();}" />
<input type="text" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode==13){doSomething2();}" />

<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="" />
```

AND I need to work that button as Enter, like pressing Enter from keyboard in javascript..

Help me..
thank you

Comment: pressing enter on what element? like textbox is in focus and enter is pressed?? it can be achieved using form submission OR you have to listen to keypress/keydown event on entire document. this is not clear from your question.

Comment: yeah when the textbox which is focused

Comment: your question is not clear, please expand it a bit

Comment: i need html button same work as keyboards enter button

Comment: So you want a new line in textbox when clicking the button?

Comment: no no.. when i press enter from keyboard this calls myfunction and when pc has no keyboard and it has a touchscreen i need enter button on HTML\

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

HTML

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="doSomething1()" />
<input type="text" onkeydown="doSomething2()" />

<input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="" />
```

Javascript

```
function doSomething1(e)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        alert("enter");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("1");
    }
}
function doSomething2(event)
{
    e = e || window.event;
    if(e.keyCode==13)
    {
        alert("enter");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("1");
    }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ogtm0jru/)